# View specs: Devise overrides the helper "resource_class" of InheritedResources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, inherited-resources

I have the following view spec:

```
RSpec.describe "boilerplates/index", type: :view do
  it "Doesn't render empty topic" do
    assign :boilerplates, [create(:boilerplate_original, topic: nil)]
    render

    expect(rendered).to have_css('.topic', text: '')
  end
end
```

The view has the following line of code:

```
resource_class.status.values.each do ...
```

This line breaks in specs, as it tells me:

```
undefined method `status' for #<Class:0x00000104cb3ec8>
```

When investigating further, the `resource_class` (which comes from InheritedResources) points to `User`, but normally, it points to `Boilerplate`.

It seems that Devise overrides the `resource_class` helper method in view specs. How can this be prevented?

Comment: Are you using Devise as well?

Comment: Yes I do. I also added some new info to the thread.

Comment: My theory is that the Devise `resource_class` method is overwriting `InheritedResources`. But you would need to look at the stack trace and see which module is being called.

Comment: How could I look at the stack trace? The stack trace of the error doesn't list inherited resources nor device gem.